# Does there exist a function whose derivative is equal to it's self composition

Tags: real-analysis

Not homework, but I was just curious whether or not there exists a function which satisfies:

$\ f'(x)=f(f(x))$

I tried differentiating both sides and working from there, but just arrived at nonsense.

Thanks.

Comment: Try $f(x)=0$, for all $x$.

Comment: @vadim123 Obviously the OP looks for a non trivial solution.